# automatically sort alphabetically in vba

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I want to sort info on my sheet according to their last name (which is column 1). there's a `form control` button on the sheet that filters the info in accordance to the name of the button. everytime each of these `form control` buttons are clicked, i want to sort the info alphabetically. so i've used the `record` on macro to see what excel does to get familiar with it but i'm quite stuck... the problem is the `r` and `countA` it gives me an error of `type mismatch`

in total i have 17 columns (A to Q - but i don't want to really set a range to the columns, just in case i add more columns later) that contains information related to the `last name` which is column 1 and starts from row 3

```
Sub btnPrinceRupert()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Set r = ws.Cells(2, 1)
Set ws = Worksheets("Master")

Call filterMyTable(xPrinceRupert)
Call changeTitle("PrinceRupert")

    r.Select
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=r, _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ws.sort

    .SetRange (WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))) 
'essentially, i want the range to be up to the last entry of the table
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, you need to set the ws before set the r value;
and the Second issue, the result of WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) is a number, not Range. so the code should write like this:

```
Sub btnPrinceRupert()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
Set r = ws.Cells(2, 1)
Call filterMyTable(xPrinceRupert)
Call changeTitle("PrinceRupert")

r.Select
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=r, _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ws.sort
.SetRange (Range("1:" & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))) 
'essentially, i want the range to be up to the last entry of the table
.Header = xlNo
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: it gives me a syntax error on `.setrange (range...)`

Comment: i've replaced the `worksheetfunction` with an object called `lastrow` as `long` and the code is `ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "A").End(xlUP).row` and for `.setrange`. i've wrote `range(lastrow)` but it prompts an error `method of range object - global failed`